# Excel: overlap bars of bar graph tool

Tags: excel, graph, charts, schedule, gantt-chart

I would like to make a bar graph similar to a [Gantt Chart](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/timeline-chart-in-excel.php) (see figure)

[image: Gantt chart]

but **only showing one row, with every bar overlapped with the others**. I want to do this supposing that I have non-overlapped periods, and the final figure is only one row with several red periods.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: For anything chart-related, see http://peltiertech.com - a great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish that with a sideways stacked bar chart:

[image: SidwaysStackedBarChart1]

And you can adjust the axis minimums and maximums to make it look better - as well as fool with some other stuff. But that is probably how I would do it. Good Luck.